# Source Merit of the person who does the burying of spouse

Tags: sources-mekorot, mourning-aveilus

I can’t recall where I saw it, but I somewhat remember is that there is some merit if the husband buries the wife or vice versa.

Does anyone know the source for it?

Comment: [Genesis 23:19] - https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.23.19?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en

Comment: What do you mean "doing the burying"? Putting the corpse into the earth?

Comment: I thought about it and I think it’s who dies first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it is a merit to bury one's wife rather a monetary obligation in return for one's כתובה (rashi Kesubos there). As we see we can even go into his possessions if he is out of town.

See [Kesubos](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.46b?lang=he)

> נשאת יתר עליו הבעל שאוכל פירות בחייה וחייב במזונותיה ובפרקונה וקבורתה
> רבי יהודה אומר אפי' עני שבישראל לא יפחות משני חלילין ומקוננת:

> If the daughter married, the husband has more rights and obligations than her
> father had before the marriage,... her burial upon her death. Rabbi
> Yehuda says: Even the poorest man of the Jewish people may not provide
> fewer than two flutes and a lamenting woman, which it was customary to
> hire for a funeral, as these too are included in the duties of
> burial.4 If the daughter married, the husband has more rights and
> obligations than her father had before the marriage,

And so rules the [Rambam](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/952888/jewish/Ishut-Chapter-Fourteen.htm#v23)

> מֵתָה אִשְׁתּוֹ חַיָּב בִּקְבוּרָתָהּ וְלַעֲשׂוֹת לָהּ מִסְפֵּד
> וְקִינִים כְּדֶרֶךְ כָּל הַמְּדִינָה. וַאֲפִלּוּ עָנִי
> שֶׁבְּיִשְׂרָאֵל לֹא יִפְחֲתוּ לוֹ מִשְּׁנֵי חֲלִילִין וּמְקוֹנֶנֶת.
> אִם הָיָה עָשִׁיר הַכּל לְפִי כְּבוֹדוֹ. וְאִם הָיָה כְּבוֹדָהּ יוֹתֵר
> מִכְּבוֹדוֹ קוֹבְרִין אוֹתָהּ לְפִי כְּבוֹדָהּ שֶׁהָאִשָּׁה עוֹלָה עִם
> בַּעְלָהּ וְאֵינָהּ יוֹרֶדֶת אֲפִלּוּ לְאַחַר מִיתָה:
>
> לֹא רָצָה לִקְבֹּר אֶת אִשְׁתּוֹ וְעָמַד אֶחָד מִדַּעַת עַצְמוֹ
> וּקְבָרָהּ מוֹצִיאִין מִבַּעְלָהּ עַל כָּרְחוֹ וְנוֹתְנִין לָזֶה
> כְּדֵי שֶׁלֹּא תִּהְיֶה זוֹ מֻשְׁלֶכֶת לַכְּלָבִים. הָיָה בִּמְדִינָה
> אַחֶרֶת כְּשֶׁמֵּתָה אִשְׁתּוֹ בֵּית דִּין יוֹרְדִין לִנְכָסָיו
> וּמוֹכְרִין בְּלֹא הַכְרָזָה וְקוֹבְרִין אוֹתָהּ לְפִי מָמוֹן הַבַּעַל
> וּלְפִי כְּבוֹדוֹ אוֹ לְפִי כְּבוֹדָהּ:
>
> When a man's wife dies, he is obligated to bury her and to have
> eulogies and lamentations performed as is the local custom. Even a
> poor Jewish man should provide at least two flutes46 and one woman to
> lament. If [her husband] is rich, [the funeral should be carried out]
> in a manner appropriate to his wealth.
>
> If the social standing of [a man's wife] exceeded his own, he must
> have her buried in a manner appropriate to her social standing. For
> [when she marries,] a woman ascends to her husband's social standing
> [if his is higher than hers], but does not descend [to his, if her
> social standing surpasses his].47 [This principle applies] even after
> death.
>
> If a husband does not desire [to pay for] the burial of his wife, and
> another person voluntarily takes the initiative and has her buried,
> [the costs of the burial] should be expropriated from her husband
> against his will and given to the person [who arranged the burial].48
> [The rationale is to prevent the body of a Jew] from being thrown to
> the dogs.
>
> If a man is in another city when his wife dies, the court should
> expropriate his property and sell it without an announcement.49 The
> woman should be buried as appropriate to her husband's financial
> resources and his social standing or her social standing.